# Optimized B+ tree implementation

Tags: java, performance, optimization, tree, b-plus-tree

I am working on a high-performance single-thread java application. My project depends on a B+ tree. Because performance is very critical, I prefer not to implement it myself and use an optimized public implementation. This way I am more assured that the implementation is fully optimized. But I couldn't find a proper implementation on Github or any other similar online source.

Where can I find a well-written java B+ tree code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this one: [BPlusTree](https://github.com/andylamp/BPlusTree)

You may also want to check [MapDB](https://github.com/jankotek/mapdb).